# Call a form in another form with button click

Tags: vb.net, forms, button

I want to open FrmNovaRegra with a button click in another form.
I already tried the basic "Dim form as new FrmNovaRegra" and "form.show()" it didnt work, how can i open it? The code of the Form that i want to open is in the next line:

```
Public Class FrmNovaRegra
    Private regras As BServices.NovaRegra

    'Private MyDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))


    Public Sub New(ByVal cls As BServices.NovaRegra)

        InitializeComponent()
        Me.regras = cls

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you specify how it didn't work (was it a crash, did it just not show? Did anything else happen which wasn't normal?) 
Also please put a breakpoint in your `Public Sub New` so you know for sure that this form is being created. Don't forget the parameter in the overload, just in case.

Comment: It says "Argument not specified for parameter cls of Public sub New (cls as NovaRegra)

Comment: [link] https://i.imgur.com/rw77sYq.png

Comment: You need to pass the parameter `cls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form needs it's parameter, because there are no other overloads. There are many ways you can correct this.

If you have the `cls As BServices.NovaRegra` you can create the form using:

```
Dim form as new FrmNovaRegra(cls)
```

If you want to create a new one on the fly, that's also possible:

```
Dim form as new FrmNovaRegra(New BServices.NovaRegra())
```

This new cls might need some parameters too, I'm not familiar with this class.

Another way to work around this would be to add a new overload which doesn't need a parameter, but your form looks like it needs the cls, so let me know if you need more explanations for this one as a comment.

Comment: The major issue here i think is that this project is integrated with a billing system than may have some conflicts. I already created another topic where i have an issue with CheckonClick items on a checkedlistbox that in a project work but when i integrated them with this billing software this property doesnt work...

Comment: You can try to limit those kind of conflicts by enforcing `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On` (as for I, I always set them like this and it saves me tons of unneeded trouble). The second thing might help you even more: if there are conflicts when you make a call, you can limit them by using the complete namespace where those calls might conflict. This saved me countless problems whenever I suspected an unexpected result, too.

Comment: Thanks friend i already solved this issue